# Any explanation for this behavior?

Tags: esp8266, string, iot, c-string

For the below code snippet

```
const char* fr_fbdb(char tag[30]) // fn for retrieving data 
{
  char full_path[120]; 
  const char *_dt ; 
  strcpy(full_path , base_path);
  strcat(full_path , tag);
  Serial.print( "retrieving from " ); 
  Serial.println(full_path) ; 
  Firebase.get(firebaseData, full_path);
  _dt = firebaseData.cstrData();
//  Serial.print("while ext: "); 
//  Serial.println(_dt); 
  return _dt ; 
} 

void retreive_sch()
{
  int no_tag = strlen(*tag) ;
  //Serial.print("no. of tags in the DB: ");
  //Serial.println(no_tag);
  const char *_data[no_tag];


  Firebase.get(firebaseData, "/SCHEDULE DETAILS/SELECTED");
  sch_no = firebaseData.cstrData();

  Serial.print("extracting schedule");
  Serial.println(sch_no);

  strcat(base_path , sch_no); // base path w/ sch no.

  for (int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++) 
  {
    _data[i] = fr_fbdb(tag[i]); 
    Serial.print("while ext: "); 
    Serial.println(_data[i]);  
    
  }

  for(int i=0 ; i<6 ; i++)
  {
    Serial.print("after extraction:"); 
    Serial.println(_data[i]) ;
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
retrieving  schedule changes -- setup 
extracting schedule3
retrieving from /SCHEDULE DETAILS/SCHEDULE3/DATE
while ext: [1609612200000,\"inf\"]
retrieving from /SCHEDULE DETAILS/SCHEDULE3/FREQ FR
while ext: \"-2\"
retrieving from /SCHEDULE DETAILS/SCHEDULE3/FREQ TO
while ext: \"-2\"
retrieving from /SCHEDULE DETAILS/SCHEDULE3/WEIGHT
while ext: 29
retrieving from /SCHEDULE DETAILS/SCHEDULE3/TIME
while ext: \"6:30\"
retrieving from /SCHEDULE DETAILS/SCHEDULE3/frequency
while ext: \"-1\"
after extraction:"root":[]
after extraction:\"-1\"
after extraction:keep-alive
after extraction:\"-1\"
after extraction:"root":[]
after extraction:\"-1\"
```

As you can see, the output of the same variable `_data[]` inside that particular function changes.
Any idea why?

Comment: I would suggest you pick up a book about C++ and understand how to use `const` and what happen and the scope of a locally declare variable within a function.

Comment: ```_data``` is a global var & both set of print statements are within the same Fn. I hv used ```const char* fr_fbdb``` bcos ```firebaseData.cstrData()``` returns a c-string. Here's how I thought the flow was going to be: I call ```retrieve_sch()``` in the ```setup()``` . Then I get no. of tags from ```strlen(*tag)``` (```tag``` holds strings such as DATE , WEIGHT, etc.). Then using a for loop that calls ```fr_fbdb()``` n no. of times get the req. tags. I also print the value that was retrieved here and in the for loop below. Pls point out where there might be flaws.

Comment: `_dt` is a locally declared variable, its scope remain local and when a call is return from the function, whatever stored in the `_dt` could be free up and the memory could be override.

Comment: "_data" has the value that is returned by the function ```fr_fbdb()``` which is confirmed by the print statements in the 1st for loop of ```retreive_sch()``` . In the second for loop of ```retreive_sch()``` the same var, ```_data``` gives different values. My claim is, if there was a pblm (bcos of scope of variables), then it should have been shown in the first print statement. (In case you haven't noticed, I've commented the print statements in ```fr_fbdb()```)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is these lines of code in your function `fr_fddb()`:

```
  Firebase.get(firebaseData, full_path);
  _dt = firebaseData.cstrData();
```

You didn't share enough code to make this clear, but `firebaseData` appears to be a global which you reuse. When you call its `.cstrData()` method you're getting a pointer to the same buffer each time, and that buffer is overwritten each time you call `Firebase.get()`.

You can verify this by printing the pointer value each time through, like so in your `retrieve_sch()` function:

```
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++) 
  {
    _data[i] = fr_fbdb(tag[i]); 
    Serial.print("while ext: "); 
    Serial.println(_data[i]);  
    Serial.printf("_data[i] pointer %p\n", _data[i]);
  }
```

You'll likely see that the 6 pointers are identical. The value is changing because you keep reusing the same string.

The easy fix is:

```
  Firebase.get(firebaseData, full_path);
  _dt = strdup(firebaseData.cstrData());
```

This allocates memory and stores in it a duplicate of the string that was fetched from Firebase. Your function will now return that and `firebaseData` can safely be reused.

This solution will require you to free that memory at some point when you're doing using it by calling `free(_dt);` or whatever you're holding the pointer in when you're done. I leave that as an exercise for you.